# how stargazer converts a model object

Tags: r, dataframe, latex, stargazer

I am using stargazer and I would like to use it for model type, that is not supporter yet. So I would like to put it into stargazer by hand.

My question is how to replicate stargazer by hand using simple `lm` function

```
model = lm(hp ~ factor(gear) + qsec, data= mtcars)
stargazer::stargazer(model, type = "text")
```

is it possible to reproduce this output by hand? that is extract all coefficients and std. erors from model, create a dataframe and insert it to `stargazer` so it would look exactlz the same?

Comment: This is fundamentally not possible. The rule of thumb for working with stargazer is: don’t. [It’s a terrible package and quite unredeemable](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use [‘texreg’](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/) instead.

Comment: @Konrad, *texreg* documentation looks solid. Also on that thread you linked, *broom* plus *pander* gets some votes as well - have you compared that workflow?

Comment: @MarkNeal texreg is more automated than the combination broom + pander, which, ultimately, still requires you to format the model table yourself. That said, I find both workflows acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

With what I have worked with `stargazer` you can insert values manually (with `latex` output) but it is very tedious but very good if you want to add extra things with LaTeX code as well as insert additional rows or columns quickly as you like, but sometimes there are errors as you can't distinguish all LaTeX code in `stargazer` as I had a problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574087/how-can-i-make-a-collapse-with-glue-package-using-rmarkdown/60686411#60686411). So I had to resort to another package called `xtable`.
In short, it depends on what you want to do. I hope I've cleared up your doubt.